# Is there a way to overload operator= to have specific behavior for a function on right hand side

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class named `Image` which I would like a non member function to return into an `Image`.

```
Image::Image(const char * src);
Image::Image& operator= (const Image& p);
Image requestImg(std::string filename); //not a member function
```

And I use it like so:

```
Image p = requestImg("grass.png");
```

This is fine, however- I would like to be able to have `requestImg` spawn a thread which loads an image into the `Image` object(p), while modifying that object to have a status of `loading=true`.

In other words.

```
Image p = requestImg("grass.png");  //image is loading
std::cout << p.loading << std::endl; //true
//some time passes
std::cout << p.loading << std::endl; //false
```

`p` cannot have loading set to true initially, as it would not be loading and would not lead to sane naming. I realize with a member function this would be easier- or even passing a pointer to the function, but is there any way to do this as I've laid out?

Comment: Why don't you call a function instead of spawning an extra thread out? Within the function call the image and at the end set to boolean to false inside one big function.

Comment: I need it to return immediately.

Comment: Why are you looking to overload the assignment operator?  The code you gave calls the copy constructor, not the assignment operator.

    `Image p = requestImg("grass.png"); `

When you instantiate an object using another (existing) object, the compiler calls the copy constructor.

Comment: @MrPickle5 You are correct, I was under the wrong impression of how c++ deals with this. I've added the function declarations below which I used to solve this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the general code I used to achieve this (well I'm close but we can call it solved). It uses the temporary futureImage to deal with the future, and the *copy* constructor overloading to create a new thread and populate `this`... in the future. Here is the types:

```
class Image {
private:
        std::future<Image> * futureImage; //just a temporary for threading
        void threadingwork(); //this takes futureimage and sets values of self once it finishes
    public:
        Image(std::future<Image> p); //this sets loading = true, and sets the future + creates a thread which calls threadingwork above
};

std::future<Image> requestImg(std::string filename);
```

So now:

```
Image p = requestImg("grass.png");
```

Resolves correctly (and uses copy constructor correctly).

Answer (score 3):

You can leave `Image` as it is, and use [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), which would give you an [`std::future<Image>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future). You can decide when you need the result of that:

```
#include <future>

auto p = std::async(std::launch::async, &requestImg,"grass.png"); // load image asynchronously
//some time passes
// do other work

// now we really need the image
auto img = p.get(); // blocking call, requires async call to be done loading image.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how I can integrate this with what I have. I mean, with the asyncs I will not have the Image object where I can check to see if it is done loading?

Comment: @jett you can, kind of. The future has two timed wait methods. These return a status telling you whether the asynchronous work has been done or not. I linked in some `std::future` docs.

Comment: Ok I see, hmm. It comes close. I will consider it, right now I am trying an overloaded = operator to spawn a thread but I don't think I will get far with it (have to wait for return.. err). I really wish there was a way to bind lhs with a future.

Comment: @jett bear in mind that `operator=` has nothing to do with it, at least not in the code you've shown. That means the question's title is a bit confusing.

Comment: Perhaps it isn't worded perfectly, but I am referring to this line: Image p = requestImg("grass.png");

Comment: @jett right, and that is an initialization, which calls constructors, not assignment operators.

Comment: ... err, right :p Well, learning everyday it seems. My apologies for the confusion.